# Not able to sent the confirmation mail to the user?

Tags: email, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm working on the Magento 1.9.2.4.

When the user (guest or logged in) type their email for subscription they don't receive the confirmation email while all the setting for has been done by me.

Comment: all other emails are working properly on your store ?

Comment: Are all other emails working fine?

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit stupid but has your customers checked that the emails don't go to their spam folder? This is the first thing that comes to my mind.

If that's not the problem I recommend checking that other emails your magento might send are working, so you can narrow it down a bit more.